# Firebase query for key

Tags: swift, firebase, key

I've got a Firebase structure as follows:

```
Goals
  - userID
    - autoKey
        - Goal_Summary: some data
```

I have the value of the autoKey from an earlier tableviewcell swipe.  I'd like to construct a query which displays the data from "Goal_Summary" into a textview.

Note, I cannot query by "some data" as this is dynamic.  Also note that there are many autoKeys under userID.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
        let refGoals = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Goals").child(userID!).queryOrdered(byChild: GoalSettingEditKey)
```

The result is that I always get the same Goal_Summary data.  This means the textview does not contain the correct data. However, I can see the auto key value change in a label I've got assigned to it.  They auto key changes correctly, but the data does not.

How do I construct the correct query, which lets me query for a specific autoKey?

Thanks in advance,

N.

Comment: Nevermind... solved as follows:

        let refGoals = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Goals").child(userID!).queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: GoalSettingEditKey)

Comment: You never need to query for a key if you know the key (and complete path). Queries are *much* heavier than observes so just use .observeSingleEvent on the path. `let pathRef = firebase.child("Goals").child(userID).child(autoKey)` and then `pathRef.observeSingleEvent...`.

Comment: Jay - you’re right.  Thanks for the suggestion. Have changed my code accordingly.